# Cannot import sklearn_pandas in Google AI Platform Notebook after pip install

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am playing around with Google's AI Platform Notebook (which is still in beta at the moment). I uploaded a python script that has dependency on sklearn_pandas and I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-24f79569b871> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper

ImportError: No module named 'sklearn_pandas'
```

I then try to pip install it:

```
!pip install sklearn-pandas
```

I restarted the kernel but it is still getting same ImportError. I did this to confirm sklearn pandas is really installed:

```
!pip list |grep -i sklearn

DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
sklearn-pandas (1.8.0)
```

Anyone has tried this? I used google colab before this, and I never have such difficulty. It will be great if Google colab level of user experience can be ported into this beta product. I think this could be a general python module importing issue than just sklearn_pandas in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it may be

```
%pip install sklearn-pandas
```

instead of "!pip".

Comment: I confirmed this on a notebook instance, problem solved.